# C# Is there a way to use a list in a TrueForAll List method

Tags: c#, list, lambda, predicate

I have a helper method that is determining if a list of email addresses match certain email domains that the application says are acceptable. The method looks like this:

```
public bool IsValidEmail(List<string> emails)
{
     return emails.TrueForAll(x => x.contains("gmail.com") || x.contains("hotmail.com") || x.contains("yahoo.com")
}
```

This works fine of course, but I'm wondering if to get rid of magic strings there is a way to have a list like

```
 var validEmailDomains = new List<string> {"gmail.com", "hotmail.com", "yahoo.com"}
```

and use this in the Predicate that is used in TrueForAll?

Comment: `x=>validDomains.All(d=>x.Contains(d))`. You could even replace `TrueForAll` with `All`, which works on any `IEnumerable<T>`. And probably use `x.EndsWith` instead of `Contains`

Comment: Side note: To avoid accepting emails like `gmail.com@evilorg.ru` or `dragon@smaugmail.com`, you'll want to actually parse the email addresses and validate that the domain portion fits one of your whitelisted domains exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=net-7.0) :

```
return emails.TrueForAll(x=>validDomains.Any(d=>x.Contains(d)));
```

or

```
return emails.All(x=>validDomains.Any(d=>x.Contains(d)));
```

`All` does for all `IEnumerable<T>`'s what `TrueForAll` did only for List

Comment: Shouldn't it be `validDomains.Any(...)`? Very few emails have all the valid domains in them. ;-)

Comment: You're right. I got stuck at `...All`

Comment: instead of .contains, you should be checking x.endswith(d) 
Example: xxyahoo.com@bullshit.com

Comment: I already wrote that in the comments